# X cannot be resolved to a variable | String/Directory error

Tags: java, string, file, directory

so I'm working on course work and I'm quite new to java.

I'm using a database that has SQL files in directories that relate to what the files are about. The user needs to be able to tell the program to look at these SQL files, it can't look at them all as there is 5000-8000 of them.

```
    String SystemDirectory = "F:/EVE M&R/bin/Resources/Systems";
    File[] Directories = new File(SystemDirectory).listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

and I'm getting an error on the second line like this

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
     M cannot be resolved to a variable
     R cannot be resolved to a variable
     Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Comment: The problem is the & at M&R. You have two options: rename it or scape the string.

Comment: how do you escape for an & symbol? I know \ would be \\ or " would be \". but I can't find anything about & online.

Answer (score 0):

To escape the &:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class testEscapeHTML{    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String testStr = "< > \" &";
        System.out.println("Original : " + testStr);
        System.out.println("Escaped : " +   StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(testStr));

    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-java/

Comment: StringEscapeUtils doesn't exist in my interpreter. is there a way to add it?

Comment: Yes. You need to download the http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/
and include it in your project as a reference library.